# Poisoned catalysts

Tags: organic-chemistry

CaCO3 in rosenmund reduction, lead in Lindlar's catalyst, or steel in Raney nickel all act as poisins but the carbon in Pd/C is just for support. How do the others affect the catalytic activity but not carbon?

Comment: Because carbon maximizes the surface area of palladium which is incorporated with it and thus helps in increasing the activity of the reaction. Other ones are just poisons which reduce catalyst activity.

Comment: Have you checked *why* lead poisons the Lindlar cat? There is a specific, individual chemical reaction behind all catalyst poisons.

Comment: Read this [Review](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0920-5861(99)00074-7).